# Alloc/init/assign new variable in C# with "new". Access a property successfully, but variable itself traces to null. WTF?

Tags: c#, null, monodevelop, unity-game-engine

I'm experiencing the following:

```
Foo myFoo = new Foo();   // Init a Foo, right?
myFoo.bar = 5;           // property assigned
Debug.Log(myFoo.bar);    // Properly traces the value 5 or whatever to the console
Debug.Log(myFoo);        // Traces "null" to the console..... WTF?!?!?!?
```

This is happening using C# in MonoDevelop in conjunction with Unity 3.5.  In this case, Foo is subclassing Object, and to my knowledge, isn't dynamic.  Is there some nuance of C# I'm missing here, because this is extremely weird behavior, and I have never seen it in ActionScript 3 or Objective-C.  It's odd to me that the runtime is able to access/assign a property of a variable that simultaneously traces "null", without even throwing a NullException or some kind of error.  Any ideas on why this might be occurring would be a huge help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where to you get the Debug.Log method you use? System.Diagnostics.Debug has no such method. Maybe it is mono specific? Also - I tried this using Debug.WriteLine() and it works as expected, outputting the type name of Foo a and 5 for the property. This was on .Net not Mono so I'm guessing the behaviour comes down to framework in some way - it isn't c# at least.

Comment: We need the `Foo` class to answer this question, at least I do, to explain what is actually going on. You do understand that `Debug.Log(myFoo);` convert the `Foo` class to a string right? So at most it would print out `System.Object` you should also post the link to the documentation for `Debug.Log` otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: Debug.Log is part of Unity's framework:
http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html
It's basically like Console.Writeline();  It takes an argument of type object and I'm assuming handles the rest internally.  I've passed many object types to this function before, and it always traces out the type passed, unless it's primitive, in which case it traces the value itself.  I'll try to post some code in a bit, it's a bit of a complicated set of classes, but the Foo in question is really just a simple data model.

Comment: Is there an override for the ToString() method of Object on class Foo? If so, is there a chance that implementation is doing something a bit out of the ordinary that would cause it to return null?

Comment: Check if the ToString() is not returnin "null" for the Foo object.

Answer (score 0):

Are you subclassing System.Object, or UnityEngine.Object?

UnityEngine.Object is a special class used to represent Unity engine objects that are backed by native representations. You shouldn't derive from it.